# Python Iterator | Google cloud logging

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I was trying to retrieve logs using Google cloud logging API and tried to use Python iterators. Below is my code:

```
import os
import pprint
from google.cloud import logging

from google.cloud.logging import ASCENDING
from google.cloud.logging import DESCENDING

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=1)

FILTER = 'resource.type="k8s_container"'

client = logging.Client()

iterator = client.list_entries(filter_=FILTER, order_by=DESCENDING)

print(type(iterator))
for page in iterator.pages:
  print('    Page number: %d' % (iterator.page_number,))
  print('  Items in page: %d' % (page.num_items,))
  print('Items remaining: %d' % (page.remaining,))
  print('Next page token: %s' % (iterator.next_page_token,))
  print('----------------------------')
  for entry in page:
      print(entry.timestamp)
```

But after executing the above program, i get the below error:

```
<class 'generator'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/suniljacob/Sunil/11-gitDownloads/19-gitlab/google_logging/cloud_loggingg.py", line 19, in <module>
    for page in iterator.pages:
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'pages'
```

Request some help from veterans as am stuck here

*P.S.: Am running on Python 3.9 and using virtualenv*

Comment: It appears from [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/page_iterator.html) that you need to call `list_resources` not `list_entries` to get an iterator that supports the `pages` attribute.

Comment: The `Client` object does not have the attribute `list_resources`

Answer (score 1):

Issue already listed in [github](https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/issues/203).

Workaround is to initialise logger client with disable grpc setting like shown below:

```
from google.cloud import logging  

client = logging.Client(_use_grpc=0)
FILTER = 'resource.type="k8s_container"'

iterator = client.list_entries(filter_=FILTER, order_by=DESCENDING)

print(type(iterator))
for page in iterator.pages:
  print('    Page number: %d' % (iterator.page_number,))
  print('  Items in page: %d' % (page.num_items,))
  print('Items remaining: %d' % (page.remaining,))
  print('Next page token: %s' % (iterator.next_page_token,))
  print('----------------------------')
  for entry in page:
      print(entry.timestamp)
```

or setting the DISABLE_GRPC environment variable to any value.